# How can you determine how much neutron shielding is necessary for a given neutron source?

Tags: fusion, neutrons

Trying to make a fusor at home and I was wondering if there is an industry standard or perhaps an equation to determine how and what type of neutron shielding is necessary to protect against the high amounts of neutrons generated from a fusion reaction such as the one that takes place in a fusor.

Comment: How can I say this gently. Maybe it's not a good idea for you to mess with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Concrete is a good cheap shielding for neutrons. The intensity of neutrons is given by I =$Ioe^{-µx}$ where µ is the neutron attenuation coefficient which is related to the neutron scattering cross section and x is the thickness of the shielding. This equation can be written as: $I/Io = e^{-µx}$. So to get 50% attenuation you just solve for x for  I/Io = 0.5. Good discussion of this is given [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00223131.2000.10874866), [here](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1107962/files/p201.pdf), and [here](https://www.eichrom.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/neutron-attenuation-white-paper-by-d-m-rev-2-1.pdf).